# For loop and an undefined index

Tags: php

It is my first time using "for" loop and I don't really understand how it works. when I tried running it, I got an error that says "undefined index...." for example Notice: Undefined index: SupplierName1. Please help me how can i get it defined. Thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$amt = $_POST['total'];
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";
if($amt > 0) {
    $qry = "INSERT INTO supplier(SupplierName, SupplierCompanyAddress, SupplierContactNo) VALUES "; // Split the mysql_query
    for($i=1; $i<=$amt; $i++) {
        $qry .= "('".$_POST["SupplierName$i"]."', '".$_POST["SupplierCompanyAddress$i"]."', '".$_POST["SupplierContactNo$i"]."', NOW()), "; // loop the mysql_query values to avoid more server loding time
    }
    $qry    = substr($qry, 0, strlen($qry)-2);
    $insert = mysql_query($qry); // Execute the mysql_query
}
// Redirect for each cases
if($insert) {
    $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "?view&result=added";</script>';
}
else {
    $msg = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Server Error, Kindly Try Again");</script>';
}
}
```

Below is the result

```
Array
(
[SupplierName1] => lloooo
[SupplierCompanyAddress1] => oo
[SupplierContactNo1] => ooo
[SupplierName2] => mm
[SupplierCompanyAddress2] => mm
[SupplierContactNo2] => mm
[total] => 2
[submit] => Add
)
```

Forgot to mention that this form can add multiple data/records at one time.

Below is the fixed version (resolved)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$amt = $_POST['total'];
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";
if($amt > 0) {
    for($i=1; $i<=$amt; $i++) {
    $qry = "INSERT INTO supplier(SupplierName, SupplierCompanyAddress, SupplierContactNo) VALUES "; // Split the mysql_query
        $qry .= " ( '".$_POST["SupplierName$i"]."' , '".$_POST["SupplierCompanyAddress$i"]."', '".$_POST["SupplierContactNo$i"]."') "; // loop the mysql_query values to avoid more server loding time
        //$qry  = substr($qry, 0, strlen($qry)-2);
        //echo $qry;//
        mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
        header('location:view_supplier_for_manager.php');
        //echo "ok";
        }else {
        echo "fail";
        }// Execute the mysql_query
    }

}
// Redirect for each cases
//if($insert) {
    //$msg = '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "?view&result=added";</script>';
}*/
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you post a SupplierName1 ?? Could you do a `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";` before the if statement and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28194470/edit) your question with the result. (The $i is defined perfectly because your script complains about SupplierName1 where the 1 comes from $i)

Comment: Just a note: Please be aware of [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [what it can lead to](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: It's not that  `$i` isn't defined. It's `SupplierName1` the one isn't defined. When you do something like `for($i = 1; $i < $someval`; $i++)` the `$i` value is being automaticly created and became 1

Comment: Your `$_POST` array doesn`t have a `SuppilerName1` key, `print_r($_POST)` would be nice.

Comment: @Rik i just edited my post

Comment: I don't see a SupplierName1 to 3 and SupplierCompanyAddress1 to 3 and  SupplierContactNo1 to 3 in your post. So you have a problem in your initial html-form. Do you have these values on your form? Maybe you should show your html form-source. (See the answer of ptrk)

Comment: So now you do have a SupplierName1. Do you still get the same `Notice: Undefined index: SupplierName1` ??

Comment: I didn't get the notice but the entered records are not added in the database @Rik

Comment: Did you get your own `Server Error, Kindly Try Again` message? If not there might be an error in your PHP. Add the following line to the top of your PHP: `$old=error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` and report back any error messages you get when posting.

Comment: It's been fixed. Thanks anyway! Would you like to see the fixed one and probably explain to me why it works (if you don't mind)? @Rik

Comment: Sure. You can also add the fixed version below your question (so others can see it too and benefit from it).

Comment: check the fixed version @Rik

Comment: I see what you're doing now and what you did wrong in the first draft. Your problem with the first one is an extra field (`, NOW()`) your using with VALUES. There is no corresponding field in the statement before that. When you delete `, NOW()` your first version should work ok. With your second version you issue all the statements separately (while the first one you did it all in one statement which should be better). In your second you already deleted the `, NOW()` yourself which is why it worked. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) There is a potential problem with your second version. You issue a header-location within the while loop. This could give a problem if the page redirects before the loop of inserting is finished. My advise is use the first version (with the `, NOW()` removed. When doing mysql_query you could read out mysql_error to see what went wrong.

Comment: Also as a final note: Your PHP is insecure and susceptible to SQL-injection. It is better to use mysqli (note the i at the end) with parameters or use PDO. (just a heads up)

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I understand how and why it works now. And about sql injection, yes I will change my code and use mysqli instead. @Rik

Comment: You may accept the answer of ptrk because that answer is correct for the initial problem with `Undefined index: SupplierName1` (and that way this question doesn't stay open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop expects that the 'indices' are in line with the `$amt` value. In other words, if the form you submitted has an input field:

```
<input type="text" name="amt" value="4"/>
```

then it should as well have 4 sets of fields like these:

```
<input type="text" name="SupplierName1"/>
<input type="text" name="SupplierCompanyAddress1"/>
<input type="text" name="SupplierContactNo1"/>

...

<input type="text" name="SupplierName4"/>
<input type="text" name="SupplierCompanyAddress4"/>
<input type="text" name="SupplierContactNo4"/>
```

The error you see happens apparently because the very first set is missing. In the loop:

```
$qry .= "('".$_POST["SupplierName$i"]."',
     '".$_POST["SupplierCompanyAddress$i"]."',
     '".$_POST["SupplierContactNo$i"]."', NOW()), ";
```

the params get expanded to:

```
$qry .= "('".$_POST["SupplierName1"]."',
     '".$_POST["SupplierCompanyAddress1"]."',
     '".$_POST["SupplierContactNo1"]."', NOW()), ";
```

then 2, 3... up to `$amt`. Event if `$amt` equals one, you need the first set. Try opening your browser dev tools (usu. F12) to see what exactly parameters are submitted.

Comment: what is the very first set that's missing? sorry i'm a beginner in php. help me

Comment: The result of your echo `print_r($_POST);` seems perfectly fine. Are you sure you got the warning again?

Comment: I didn't get the warning but the entered records are not added in the database